# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.82 and now I am able to start the server through the terminal. But when it comes to configuring the tomcat in the eclipse I am specifying the path of Tomcat Installation directory to: "/Users/mshikher/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/".
After this I am getting error like:'Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.'
Why I am getting this error now?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem today. Changing the permission fixed it.

```
chgrp -R tomcat /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.6
chown -R tomcat /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.6
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.6
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure it is downloaded properly, because it might occurs if some of the jars missed in tomcat/lib folder.